# Shellshock - Response of URL having CGI extension

Tags: security, cgi, shellshock-bash-bug

Why do we always check for 500 response in shellshock exploitable request why not 200, 301 or others?

```py
conn.request("GET", path, headers=headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
if res.status == 500:
    print "Shell Shock Exploitable"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a standard way to check if a server is vulnerable to the [shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)) bug.

As an example, suppose we have a [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) script running on [Apache](https://www.apache.org/), accessible via the URL `http://localhost/shellshock.cgi`, and we make a request that passes some new custom header like this:

```py
import requests

url = 'http://localhost/shellshock.cgi'

# Checking if the server is vulnerable
headers = {
    'shellshock': '() { :; }; echo vulnerable;'
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 500:
    print('Panic! The server is vulnerable!')
else:
    print('Phew, looks like the server has been patched')
```

The header itself is just a dummy header that looks like a function definition (with an empty statement as the body), followed by an ordinary `echo` command.

Now, according to https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2014-6271:

> GNU Bash through 4.3 processes trailing strings after function
> definitions in the values of environment variables, which allows
> remote attackers to execute arbitrary code via a crafted environment.

This means that a vulnerable server should return a 500 [Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) in the above case.

The reason for this is that the request headers passed to the server are stored as environment variables, in which case the `echo` command after the function is executed unintentionally when the function is imported -- but *before* the CGI script gets to print its valid headers.

In the Apache error logs, you would see something about a *"malformed header"* or *"bad header"* -- since in this case, the output from the `echo` command (`vulnerable`) is the *first* thing that gets printed and is therefore treated as a header.

The fact that a 500 error occurs lets us know that *something* went wrong. Its not full-proof though, since an Internal Server Error could have occurred for any amount of other reasons. However, this approach gives a pretty good indication.

Of course, the above is just a simple way to demonstrate that the server is vulnerable. Once we know the server is vulnerable, we can try to exploit it like this:

```py
import requests

url = 'http://localhost/shellshock.cgi'

# Trying to exploit the vulnerability
headers = {
    'shellshock': '() { :; }; echo Content-type: text/html; echo; cat /etc/passwd;'
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Here we just add the necessary [`Content-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header followed by a blank line *before* attempting to execute arbitrary malicious code. This prevents the 500 Internal Server Error, thereby enabling the output of the malicious code to be returned when the CGI script terminates.

If our exploit succeeds, then we should get a 200 [OK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) response from the server, and see the contents of the `/etc/passwd` file. So you could treat this a check for the shellshock vulnerability as well - one that doesn't rely on merely checking for a 500 error.

Of course, in the above case we're just echoing back the contents of the `/etc/passwd` file, but we could easily exploit shellshock to do significant damage to the server and/or its users. There is a good [Cloudflare](https://blog.cloudflare.com/inside-shellshock/) article that explores various possibilities.

Recommend Reading:

- [Wikipedia article on Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug))
- [NIST vulnerability entry](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2014-6271)
- [Blog post from Cloudflare](https://blog.cloudflare.com/inside-shellshock/)
- [Article from OWASP](https://owasp.org/www-pdf-archive/Shellshock_-_Tudor_Enache.pdf)
- [Article from IBM](https://securityintelligence.com/articles/shellshock-vulnerability-in-depth/)